# Vimtex in Spacevim: conceal persists even on cursor line

Tags: conceal, plugin-vimtex, spacevim

I am new to (space)vim and I tried to make vimtex work in spacevim.
Following the documentation, I added the layer:

```
[[layers]]
name = 'lang#latex'
```

in init.toml. Opening a .tex document then the math symbols, but the concealment is maintained, even if the cursor (in either Visual or Insert mode) is on that line, for example:
[image]

I tried to play around with conceallevel and tex_conceal, by adding the option

```
bootstrap_before = 'myspacevim#before'
```

in the init.toml. Then, inside myspacevim.vim, I added the function

```
function! myspacevim#before() abort
   let g:tex_flavor='latex'
   let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
   let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
   set conceallevel=0
   let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
   nnoremap jk <Esc>
endfunction
```

I expected that nothing would be concealed because of conceallevel=0, but this command seems to be completely ignored (unlike the other "let" command).
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: as suggested by D. Ben Knoble, the conceallevel and concealcursor
cursor work as expexcted if I set them manually inside vim, e.g. by doing,

```
:set conceallevel=2
:set concealcursor=n
```

This means that somehow, these instruction are not read/overwritten in the bootstrap functions?

Comment: You might want to check out `'concealcursor'`

Comment: I did play around with it, but it also seems to be ignored?

Comment: to be honest I’m not 100% sure how either vimtex or spacevim works. You should be able to `:set` concealcursor or conceallevel interactively until you find something that works, though, and then maybe someone can help figure out how to set those things more permanently/automatically for you